# How to output ActiveView to JPEG image using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, c#, jpg

I have an ArcGIS Desktop extension and I need to extract images from the map.

How can I programmatically output the active view to a jpeg image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two Visual Studio snippets that exports the active view as a JPEG:

- [Create JPEG (hi-resolution) from ActiveView Snippet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/#/Create_JPEG_hi_resolution_from_ActiveView_Snippet/0049000000nv000000/) :

> Creates a .jpg (JPEG) file from IActiveView using a high resolution
>   exporting option. Default values of 96 DPI are overwritten to 300 used
>   for the image creation.

- [Create JPEG from ActiveView Snippet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/#/Create_JPEG_from_ActiveView_Snippet/004900000064000000/) :

> Creates a .jpg (JPEG) file from IActiveView. Default values of 96 DPI
>   are used for the image creation.